# SSLPeerUnverifiedException while working with HTTPS in android

Tags: java, android, rest, https

In android I am working with RESTful API with HTTPS protocol

```
HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                    request.setURI(new URI(UrlConnectionConstants.SCI_TA_AGENT_URL));
                    response = client.execute(request);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               return response;
```

resulting SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

Comment: I think `HttpClient` has been deprecated, i suggest you use `HttpURLConnection` for `http` connections and `HttpsURLConnection` for `https` connections
More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095813/androidhttpclient-versus-httpurlconnection-for-api-level-9-and-above#answer-22096707

Comment: There is no `SSLPeerUnspicifiedException`. Do you mean `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`?

Comment: thanks for response but I have same issue with HttpsURLConnection class also

Comment: SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Comment: Is the certificate a self signed certificate, at the server?

Comment: yes.Its a self signed certificate

Comment: for a self signed certificate you need to do a little bit more coding than usual, i will post a sample using `HttpsUrlConnection` in a while

Comment: @Deb okay.that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample piece of code for Self-signed certificates for HTTPS connection

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    HttpsURLConnection client=null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(appendedUrl);
        client= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        client.setRequestMethod("GET");
        client.setRequestProperty("Auth-Token", token);
        client.setConnectTimeout(120000);
        client.setReadTimeout(120000);
        if(appendedUrl.contains("https")) {
            client.setSSLSocketFactory(certificatePinning(context).getSocketFactory());//for certificate pinning
            client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    if (hostname.equals("YOUR-HOST-ADDRESS"))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            });
        }
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return new JSONObject(result);
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Additionally you can check this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092857/sslpeerunverifiedexception-while-creating-an-ssl-connection-on-android?rq=1